# How to incorporate the img and data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this

```
<img src="http://www.lab..whatever/<? echo <span id="accntVisaPhotoPath"></span>";?>" height="50" width="50">
```

I already have the data (dynamically)

and I have this script

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('select').change(function(){
            var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
            $('#visanumber').html(selected.data('visanumber')); 
            $('#idnumber').html(selected.data('idnumber')); 
            $('#statusapp').html(selected.data('statusapp')); 
            $('#accntVisaPhotoPath').html(selected.data('accntVisaPhotoPath')); 
            $('#passportPath').html(selected.data('passportPath')); 
        }).change();
    });
</script>
```

What is wrong with the `img` line?

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but, did your first line is compiling ? Because usually you should use echo with `" "` to properly print some string, thing you did not do in your first line.

Comment: Now just that you are going to end up with an image with the src attribute as : `http://www.lab..whatever/<span id="temp"></span>`. Which is **not** a valid request URL and so the image will not be rendered

Comment: Why are you echoing a `span` element inside the `src` property??

Comment: Sorry.. I have edited my <span id>

Comment: @Grengas you are right, which one need to change?

Comment: @Grengas, that doesnt work :(

Comment: I need to echo the data attributes inside the img tag

Comment: Off topic, but, Jong, did you know that you could also comment the answers given to your questions ? That's better if you want to address if you want to address a particular answer's author because they will get notified of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add span tag as attribute of img tag. So this is what is wrong with img line. You should echo your span after the img tag is closed or echo something else but not span tag.

I guess you want to change img src attribute dynamically, so in this case you should give some id to img and then to change its src attribute with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add span in image src tag or no need to echo span

```
 <span id="accntVisaPhotoPath"><img src="http://www.lab..whatever/" height="50" width="50"></span>
```

and use your script like this

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var $parent = $(this).parents("tr");
        $parent.find('#visanumber').html(selected.data('visanumber')); 
        $parent.find('#idnumber').html(selected.data('idnumber')); 
        $parent.find('#statusapp').html(selected.data('statusapp')); 
        $parent.find('#accntVisaPhotoPath').html(selected.data('accntVisaPhotoPath')); 
        $parent.find('#passportPath').html(selected.data('passportPath')); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you specify relation between img tag and javascript??

Comment: Here is my [lab](http://www.lab.workforceint.com/contract.php), dynamically provided by my db

Comment: if your html not break anywhere above code work fine. if you have any problem, you can ask.

Comment: It doesnt break though

Comment: I have this "GET http://www.lab.workforceint.com/%3Cspan%20id= 500 (Internal Server Error) " in my console